# How to make a procedural node setup to for raindrop effect for EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, procedural, eevee-render-engine

I just saw this amazing video that shows procedural raindrop effect using a node setup in EEVEE, created by [this](https://twitter.com/Erisdraw3D) person. It's not possible to see the node setup from the video. So I wonder if someone knows how to create a node setup that does what's being shown in the video.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a Voronoi texture node to control roughness and normal (bump). Use a mapping node to stretch the texture in z-axis and animate the z-axis location to make the rain drops run down the sides:

[image]

On top of this, try to experiment with a noise texture to modulate the x and y axis to make the drops go down in a not so straight line.

Note: This approach only really work well on cube-like geometry with rounded corners.

---

**EDIT**: I worked further on this and with inspiration from Eris answer I updated the setup to the following:

[image]

The two voronoi textures are animated independently to make two sets of raindrops of slightly different sizes and speeds.

[image: Rain drops result]

Even though I used Eevee for the above example, this works perfectly fine with Cycles as well. The first example was made using Cycles in 2.79, the second with Eevee in a recent 2.8 build.

---

Here is the .blend-file (Note: this is a Blender 2.8 file):

[image]

Comment: So does this give you the raindrop-moving-effect when you start rendering like what is being shown in the video?

Comment: Yes, if you animate the mapping nodes z-axis location.

Comment: Quite possibly the example in your question uses multiple instances of mapping nodes / voronoi nodes to make a couple of layers with drops of different sizes and different speeds. But the basic setup should look something like what I showed.

Comment: Could you please work on it a bit more so that you can literally make something that depicts what the video shows. Then I can accept your post as the answer to my question.

Comment: If you want replicate exactly what the video depicts I think your better off asking the author of the video for the .blend-file. And also, isn’t experimenting on your own the best (and most fun) way to learn?

Comment: I might investigate further on this later on, since I also think this is a very nice effect. But not right now.

Comment: Great job! It's amazing!. Btw, I had already asked the author to share the node set up but he/she did not respond.

Comment: Would you mind putting a blend file up? It saves people from tediously copying the node tree. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the .blend file has been added.

Comment: @TobiasEinarsson He/she just [posted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgGGTEiuz3Y) a video of the work. Looks much more complicated than yours but I would say yours is more realistic. Great job again!

Comment: @TobiasEinarsson I recently came across this again. I wonder, how do you "animate" the Voronoi textures?

Comment: By keyframing the ”Location” Z-values of the Mapping-nodes (the values are highlighted in green in the screenshot).

Answer (score 2):

use a UV distortion to make rain drop more natural.
in this case i use a wave texture to deform. like this
[image]

Comment: Could you please post a .gif of what you've made or at least upload the *.blend* file [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and put the link in your response?